# Post build command doesn't work in not startup project

Tags: c#

I have a `wav` file in project. File reside under `Res` dir

[image]

I need this file to be copy to the `TargetDir`, so in order to do it I added post build command (`Right click on project -> Properties -> Build events`). Command is -

```
copy $(ProjectDir)\Res\*.wav $(TargetDir)\*.*
```

[image]

So, I expect that after solution was built this `wav` file should be copied to `TargetDir`, but it actually no.

What am I missing here?

P.S. This `RecordTabEngine` is not a StartupProject. If I make the same but on Startup project it is works well. Looks like post build command works just on startup project

Comment: If you go to the properties for the actual item, I believe there is actually an option for "copy to output directory."

Comment: @Omaha actually yes, thanks! But anyway it is interesting why it doesn't work by post build command

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if you remove the \\*.* from the end of the command?  I've never seen copy used that way.